# Bot reply In DM on a specific message. Discord.net

Tags: vb.net, discord.net

I'm trying to make a bot that sends a private message when triggered by a specific word.

For example, it would trigger if I type 'send_me_dm'

After the bot sends me a dm message, if I were to dm back 'hiiii", the bot will reply in the dm 'hi'

My code :

```vb
If message.Content.Contains("send_me_dm") Then
    Dim user = TryCast(message.Author, SocketGuildUser)
    Await user.SendMessageAsync("you can talk with me") 'now it send as dm
End If

Dim channell As SocketTextChannel = discord.GetChannel(message.Channel.Id)

If message.Channel.Id.Equals(channell) Then
    If message.Content.Contains("hiiii") Then      
        Await channell.SendMessageAsync("hi")   
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Ideally you should use the [Command Service](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/commands/intro.html) that's provided with discord.net. Using that along with the [Discord.Addons.Interactive](https://github.com/foxbot/Discord.Addons.Interactive) package you can accomplish what you want relatively easily.

Comment: Issues with code: `Dim channell As SocketTextChannel = discord.GetChannel(message.Channel.Id)` - You already have `message.Channel` this GetChannel() call is redundant, simply cast the `message.Channel` to a `SocketTextChannel`. Additionally, you cannot compare a channel's id to a channel object - `message.Channel.Id.Equals(channell)` - this line will **never** be true. It should be `If message.Channel.Id = channell.Id`. Even with these changes though, this program flow will not work. If "hiiii" is sent in a server channel the bot will simply respond in the same channel with "hi"